# Foreach loop for two arrays?

Tags: php

I have two arrays. One for input boxes and other for checkbox.

inputbox[]    checkbox[]

inputbox[]    checkbox[]
.
.
.
.
submit button

When I fill check box1 and fill the value in input box1 and try to submit.
Foreach fails because it pass all the indexes of input boxes but only passes checked checkbox.

```
foreach(array_combine($checkbox, $inputbox) as $check => $input)
```

Please tell me what can i do?

Comment: You can post some real code so we can help you better.

Comment: unchecked checkboxes do not POST. keep that in mind.

Comment: Please post Your code what you are trying.. html , php code or if u using jquery code,,,so we will help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have a control over the HTML form you can make the form in following manner

```
<input type="text" name="name[1]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check[1]" />
<input type="text" name="name[2]" /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="check[2]" /> 
<input type="text" name="name[3]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check[3]" />
<input type="text" name="name[4]" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check[4]" />
```

in that case you will get the post array in the following manner

```
Array
(
    [name] => Array
        (
            [1] => Swapnil
            [2] => 
            [3] => Sarwe
            [4] => Swapnil Sarwe
        )

    [check] => Array
        (
            [1] => on
            [3] => on
        )

)
```

Now you can loop over the name(input box) and then check isset for the isset($_POST['check'][$key]) and set the default value

Comment: Can You Please tell me in more detail? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over textboxes (which are guaranteed to all be present), then fetch the corresponding checkbox (probably by ID, if you have some kind of ID correspondence between them - which you should).